# Vanilla Javascript form serialization not working with multiple choice select boxes

Tags: javascript, serialization

I am trying to serialize some form data and it's working great if there's only one checkbox checked, but if I try to check more than one checkbox it is only getting the value of the first checkbox that is checked.

```js
var serializeForm = function (form) {
    var obj = {};
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    for (var key of formData.keys()) {
        obj[key] = formData.get(key);
    }
    return obj;
};

document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = JSON.stringify(serializeForm(e.target));
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>
    Lorem
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="lorem" checked />
  </label>
  <label>
    Ipsum
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="ipsum" checked />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I adjust the serialize function so that it will return both values if both checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FormData.getAll` to get all values under a specific name as an array. However for "normal" inputs you might want the value as string. I've added a primitive yet effective  way to detect by name which method to use: `get` or `getAll`.

```js
var serializeForm = function(form) {
  var obj = {};
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  for (var key of formData.keys()) {
    if (key.endsWith('[]')) {
      obj[key] = formData.getAll(key);
    } else {
      obj[key] = formData.get(key);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = JSON.stringify(serializeForm(e.target));
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="single" value="regular">
  <label>
    Lorem
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="lorem" checked />
  </label>
  <label>
    Ipsum
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="ipsum" checked />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```